# paramiko object method exec_command doesn't execute shell script

Tags: python, linux, shell, ssh, paramiko

this is 3rd hour of me knowing the existence of something which is called paramiko.

my requirement: run a py script on windows that connects to remote linux server, executes a shell script there and take output of whatever shell script prints and return to python script and print it on python windows terminal.

I am able to connect through ssh. Opening channel and session both working.

Issue: SshObj.exec_command doesn't work for some commands or scripts.
However, I tried with normal "ls" command. same SshObj.exec_command call is working fine.

below is snippet:

```
>>> ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
>>> ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
>>> ssh.connect(IP,22,usname,pswd)
>>> stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('/home/scripts/a.sh')
>>> stdout.channel.recv_ready()
False
>>> stdout.channel.recv_ready()
False
>>> stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('/home/scripts/a.sh')
>>> stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('ls')
>>> stdout.channel.recv_ready()
True
```

Comment: Does your a.sh have execute permissions on it (chmod 755 a.sh)?

Comment: And what is the output of a.sh?  recv_ready() does not indicate a command has completed. It only tells you there is something that can be read from the channel.  If your command does not return any output,  recv_ready() returns always false, despite your command completing absolutely fine.

Comment: You should check standard error as well as standard output. If the script is failing to run for some reason, you're probably getting an error message on stderr.

Comment: Hannu, Yes a.sh has 755 permissions. 
a.sh contains only 1 echo command. (echo "Ssh Success from windows. I am running in linux 2U now")

a.sh output:

$ ./a.sh

Ssh Success from windows. I am running in linux now

$

Comment: It is very strange to observe that even the "stdout.channel.recv_ready()" gives "False",

if I read from stdout, it gives required output.

stdout.channel.recv(4096)

b' Ssh Success from windows. I am running in linux now\n'